# Потоки в JavaFX

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, gui

Есть фрагмент кода:

```
public class LyricNN extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        HBox vhidDann = new HBox(5);
        root.getChildren().add(vhidDann);

        Label lbl = new Label("Total Error");
        NeuralNetwork nn1 = new NeuralNetwork(262, new int[]{262,262/*,262,262*/,262});
        nn1.setLabel(lbl);

        Button btn = new Button("Train");
        btn.setOnAction(act -> {
            trainNetwork(nn1);
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(lbl,btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);


        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static void trainNetwork(NeuralNetwork nn){
        new Thread(() -> {
            //obj.method1();
            double taskSet[][] = loadArrayFromFile("E:\\Users\\Den\\Desktop\\jar\\Task.txt", 4, 262);
            double answerSet[][] = loadArrayFromFile("E:\\Users\\Den\\Desktop\\jar\\Answer.txt", 4, 262);
            nn.trainNeuralNetwork(taskSet, answerSet, 0.5, 0.4);
        }).start();
    }
}
```

суть в том что метод `trainNetwork` заставляет интерфейс JavaFX подвисать, и я попробовал запустить его в отдельном потоке, но тот способ (`new Thread(() -> {}).start();`) запускать в отдельном потоке который известен мне не подходит, выдаёт ошибку

> Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on
>   FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4

Подскажите как в интерфейсе JavaFX правильно запускать методы в отдельных потоках.

Upd.
Проблема вот в чём: предоставленная программа - это интерфейс, а класс NeuralNetwork - выполняет логику, чтобы отображать ход выполнения логики, я передаю в класс NeuralNetwork метку (элемент интерфейса JavaFX - Label), и компилятор ругается на ошибку

> Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on
>   FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4

именно в коде класса отвечающего за логику (NeuralNetwork) вот в этом участке кода:

```
if(label!=null)label.setText("total error - "+totalErr);
```

Надеюсь это привнесет ясность, так как приведенные ниже советы к сожалению не помогли.

Comment: Покажите код, который у Вас получился на данный момент. Вы используете реализацию Task? Вам правильно ошибка валиться, так как Вы меняете свойство вне FX application thread. Мой пример ниже абсолютно такой как вам нужно, только используйте свой компонент.

Comment: LyricNN.java - это отдельный проэкт, остальные 6 файлов - другой проэкт.
https://ru.files.fm/u/5j68rfzp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откорректировал пример под Ваш случай (с Label) + [для ознакомления](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm):

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.concurrent.Task;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Test extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            VBox root = new VBox(5);
            HBox vhidDann = new HBox(5);
            root.getChildren().add(vhidDann);

            Label lbl = new Label("Total Error");
            Label lblOut = new Label("Out");
            ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();

            Button btn = new Button("Train");
            btn.setOnAction(act -> {
                trainNetwork(lblOut);
            });

            root.getChildren().addAll(lbl, btn, lblOut);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);


            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public void trainNetwork(Label label) {
            Task task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                    final int max = 1000;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(5);


                        //updateProgress(i, max);

                        this.updateMessage(i + "");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };

            label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
            new Thread(task).start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уточнил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста, надеюсь станет яснее.

Answer (score 4):

Почти все GUI-библиотеки в мире не являются потокобезопасными. Поэтому каждая библиотека предлагает механизмы запуска фоновых задач и взаимодействия с ними. В JavaFX такими механизмами являются [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) и [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html):

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;

public class LyricNN extends Application {
    ...

    btn.setOnAction(act -> {
        Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        trainNetwork(nn1);
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        service.start();
    });

    ...

    public static void trainNetwork(NeuralNetwork nn) {
        double taskSet[][] = loadArrayFromFile("E:\\Users\\Den\\Desktop\\jar\\Task.txt", 4, 262);
        double answerSet[][] = loadArrayFromFile("E:\\Users\\Den\\Desktop\\jar\\Answer.txt", 4, 262);
        nn.trainNeuralNetwork(taskSet, answerSet, 0.5, 0.4);
    }
}
```

Почитать можно [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: Уточнил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста, надеюсь станет яснее.

Comment: Это никак не изменяет моего ответа. Вам надо запустить `trainNetwork` внутри `Task` и всё будет в порядке.

Answer (score 2):

Я лично, чтобы изменять UI с потока JavaFx использую либо
        AnimationTimer или Platform.runLater
        но в основном AnimationTimer

```
    boolean update=false;
    AnimationTimer animationTimer=new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            // от здесь уже процесс от JavaFx,  можешь спокойно обновлять UI
            if(update){
                update=false;
                // обычно у меня так выглядет
                // TODO обновление UI
            }
        }
    };
    animationTimer.start();
```

runLater почему-то я пока нигде ни использовал, но пробывал

```
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //  здесь уже поток от JavaFx
        }
    });
```

есть еще пару способов связанный с чем-то типа Task, но его не опробовал, из за усложненности