# Нарисовать графики функций в разных потоках - Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, gui, concurrency

Создать многопоточное приложение, которое рисует графики двух функций. За каждую функцию отвечает отдельный поток. Также, должна быть предусмотрена возможность задания приоритетов потокам.
[image]

Собственно, как это сделать?

Насколько я понимаю, графику в окне рисует только один поток. Или же можно реализовать в нескольких?

Мои попытки осуществить это:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import static java.lang.Math.*;


public class Controller{
    @FXML
    public ChoiceBox cbSecond;
    @FXML
    public ChoiceBox cbFirst;
    @FXML
    public TextField aLabel;
    public LineChart ch1;
    public LineChart ch2;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
        cbFirst.setItems(items);
        cbSecond.setItems(items);
        cbSecond.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        cbFirst.getSelectionModel().selectLast();

        aLabel.setText("42");
    }

    static double log(double x, double base)
    {
        return (Math.log(x) / Math.log(base));
    }

    private double F1(double a, double x){
        return (pow(a, 4)) / sqrt(a * a + 2 * sin(pow(abs(x), 3) + 1));
    }

    private double F2(double x){
        return (log((x * x + 1), 2) + log(pow(abs(x), 5), 2)) / pow(abs(x), 3) + 1;
    }



    public void plotBtnClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        XYChart.Series firstline = new XYChart.Series();
        firstline.setName("F1");
        XYChart.Series secondline = new XYChart.Series();

        double a = Double.parseDouble(aLabel.getText());
        int firstPriority = Integer.parseInt(cbFirst.getValue().toString());
        int secondPriority = Integer.parseInt(cbSecond.getValue().toString());

        Runnable r1 = () -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    firstline.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, F1(i, a)));
                }
                ch1.getData().add(firstline);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        Runnable r2 = () -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    secondline.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, F2(i)));
                }
                ch2.getData().add(secondline);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        Thread th1 = new Thread(r1);
        Thread th2 = new Thread(r2);
        th1.setPriority(firstPriority);
        th2.setPriority(secondPriority);
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Нельзя работать с компонентами графического интерфейса из потоков.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794179/204271)

Answer (score 0):

Замените строки:

```
ch2.getData().add(secondline);
...
ch1.getData().add(firstline);
```

на

```
Platform.runLater(() -> ch1.getData().add(firstline));
...
Platform.runLater(() -> ch2.getData().add(secondline));
```

P.S.: Но лучше использовать [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), для этого он собственно и есть)