# JavaFX как запустить функцию в UI после выполнения потока в другом классе

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, gui

Есть поток который выполняет большие вычисления, и после того как собрал все данные, их надо отобразить в UI но при этом, пока поток работает интерфейс встает колом из за цикла while который ждет завершения потока, чтобы запустить функции отображения информации на графиках.

Вот код запуска:

```
 @FXML
 void Start() throws UnsupportedFlavorException, InterruptedException, 
 IOException {
    Programm p = new Programm();
    GlobalConstants gc = new GlobalConstants();
    Indicator.setVisible(true);
    p.ReadFrame();

    while (true) {

        synchronized (gc) {
            if (gc.flag == 3) {
                labelPredict.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", gc.predict * 1000)) + "мм");
                ChartSpeedSetter();
                ChartCoordSetter();
                ChartCoordPDSetter();
                ChartSpeedPDSetter();
                //ChartLeftFrimeSetter();
                Indicator.setVisible(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

функция Start запускается кнопкой, далее из другого класса запускается функция с вычислениями p.ReadFrame();

А в while синхронизируется переменная из потока, которая по окончанию работы выставляет flag=3, во время пока работает поток ReadFrame нужно что бы не вставал колом интерфейс, но по окончанию заполнял графики.

P.S. пробовал через task и service, таск не может изменять элименты UI либо я не так делаю(везде примеры с обновлением ProgressBar) т.е. он просто ругается на функции которые я передаю ему.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потоки в JavaFX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794078/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javafx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша кнопка при нажатии выполняет свой блок кода в FX потоке, который предназначен только для изменения графики, отсюда и зависание программы пока выполняется долгая операция. Очевидно, что долгую операцию нужно вынести в другой поток. Task, Service, да хоть new Thread для этого более чем подойдут. Изменения графики действительно возможны только в FX потоке, иначе вы получить экшепшен, который и получаете. Что бы попасть в FX тред из любого места нужно обернуть код в

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
});
```

В блоке run вам соответственно нужен будет правильный экземпляр класса контроллера или его переменных, которым надо проставить значения.
Это некие базовые принципы на простых механизмах.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое, я хоть и знал про runLater но вставлял его не там где надо, поэтому он ругался.

```
void Start() throws UnsupportedFlavorException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        Programm p = new Programm();
        GlobalConstants gc = new GlobalConstants();
        Indicator.setVisible(true);
        p.ReadFrame();

        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                while (true) {

                    synchronized (gc) {
                        if (gc.flag == 3) {
                            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {


                                    labelPredict.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", gc.predict * 1000)) + "мм");
                                    ChartSpeedSetter();
                                    ChartCoordSetter();
                                    ChartCoordPDSetter();
                                    ChartSpeedPDSetter();
                                    //ChartLeftFrimeSetter();
                                    Indicator.setVisible(false);

                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

        };


        new Thread(task).start();
    }
```