# Ошибка при выполнении функции во время работы JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, сокет

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;


public class GUIController implements Initializable {

  Socket socket;
    @FXML
    private Button connectServer;

    @FXML
    private TextArea inCon;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox scan;

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progress;

    @FXML
    private TextField commandOut;

    @FXML
    private Button recv;

    @FXML
    private TextField D2;

    @FXML
    private TextField D1;

    @FXML
    private TextField Add;

    @FXML
    private Button disconnector;

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progressFile;

    @FXML
    private TextField bytes;

    BufferedReader in;

    PrintWriter out;

    boolean connect;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
                recv.setDisable(true);
                connectServer.setOnAction(event -> {
                    new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                if(scan.isSelected()){msgCon("Сканирование запускаеться");
                 String[] are = D1.getText().toString().split("\\.");
                 String[] are1 = D2.getText().toString().split("\\.");
                 msgCon("Сканирование запущено");connectServer.setDisable(true);
                 for(int i = Integer.parseInt(are[2]);i <= Integer.parseInt(are1[2]);i++){
                     for(int u = 1;u <= 255;u++){
                         if(new String(are[0]+are[1]).equalsIgnoreCase(are1[0]+are1[1])){
                             String add = are[0]+"."+are[1]+"."+i+"."+u;
                             msgCon("Проверка адреса : "+add);
                             try {
                                 connect(add);
                                add = null;are = null;are1 = null;break;
                             } catch (IOException ex) {msgCon("Адрес неверен.");msgCon("/clear/");}
                         }else{msgCon("Напишите диапозон с одинаковыми первыми и вторыми значениями.");}

                     }
                 }
                }
                else{try {
                    progress.setProgress(0.2);connectServer.setDisable(true);
                    connect(Add.getText().toString());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {msgCon("Ошибка подключения или сервер ненайден.");connectServer.setDisable(false);progress.setProgress(0);}}}
}).start();

                });
                disconnector.setOnAction(event ->{
                disconnect(socket);
                });

                recv.setOnAction(event ->{ try{
                String msg = commandOut.getText().toString();
                if(msg != null){out.println(msg);out.flush();commandOut.setText("");}}catch(Exception e){msgCon("Сообщение не отправлено.");msgCon("Проверте соединение.");}
                });

    }
    public void connect(String add) throws IOException{
    connect = false;
    msgCon("Подключение к серверу.");
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(add,6988),50);
     if(!socket.isClosed()&&socket != null){ in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
       msgCon("Проверка сервера");
       progress.setProgress(0.4);
     out.println("258963");out.flush();
    Thread opo = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
     try{String opon = in.readLine();
     if(opon.equalsIgnoreCase("369852")){connect = true;msgCon("Проверка пройдена.");}
     }catch(IOException e){msgCon("При проверке произошла ошибка.");}
    }});
     opo.start();
     try{Thread.sleep(2000);}catch(Exception e){}
     progress.setProgress(0.6);
     opo.interrupt();
     if(connect){msgCon("Запуск всех инструментов для работы.");connector(socket);}else{msgCon("Сервер был ненайден или не прошёл проверку.");disconnect(socket);}
     }

    }
    Thread opos;
    public void connector(Socket sock){
        try {socket = sock;sock.setSoTimeout(0);progress.setProgress(0.8);} catch (SocketException ex) {}
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                opos = Thread.currentThread();
                recv.setDisable(false);
                while(true){
             try{String msg = in.readLine();
             if(msg!=null){msgCon(msg);progress.setProgress(0);}
             }catch(IOException e){msgCon("Ошибка в приёме сообщения,отключаемся.");disconnect(sock);break;}
            }}
        }).start();



    }
    public void disconnect(Socket sock){
    if(sock!=null&&!sock.isClosed()){try{sock.close();}catch(IOException e){}}
    connectServer.setDisable(false);
    recv.setDisable(true);
    in = null;
    out = null;
    msgCon("Отключены от сервера.");
    progress.setProgress(0);
    }

    public void msgCon(String msg){
    if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("/clear/")){inCon.setText("");}
    inCon.setText(msg+"\n"+inCon.getText());
    }


}
```

Не могу понять в чём ошибка пробовал различные способы менял структуру нечего не помогает,после моих попыток я смог только задержать ошибку не сразу появляется.
Ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clientcontrol.GUIController$1.run(GUIController.java:76)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.addTextRun(PrismTextLayout.java:755)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.addTextRun(GlyphLayout.java:140)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:210)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:770)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1021)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:223)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:246)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Text.java:358)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_computeGeomBounds(Text.java:1168)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1596)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.computeLocalBounds(Node.java:3595)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateLocalBounds(Node.java:3625)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1596)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1596)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_intersectsBounds(Node.java:5015)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_pickNodeLocal(Region.java:2931)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_pickNode(Node.java:4914)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:3899)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1600(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:1942)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$6700(Scene.java:159)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3799)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:559)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1719)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:559)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1719)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:559)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1719)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Это не все ошибки но они там повторяются.

Comment: Где 76 строка, что там именно null, как создаете контроллер?

Comment: Какой контролер,я пока ещё не совсем разбираюсь где что.

Comment: Как вы получили экземпляр GUIController

Comment: На похожий вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794078/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-javafx) дали ответ, посмотрите: